# using nginx location blocks to address multiple sites in root

Tags: nginx, configuration, location

I have been trying to address site folders in my root using the nginx location block, but this is not working. I wondered if my understanding of location addressing was faulty.

I have the following in nginx/sites-enabled/default:

```
index index.php index.html index.htm;

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name allsites;

  root /allsites;
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;

  location ~ /site1 {
    root /allsites/site1/public;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;

    location ~ \.php$ {
      include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
      fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }
  }

  location ~ /site2 {
    root /allsites/site2/public;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;

    location ~ \.php$ {
      include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
      fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
  }

  location ~ /\.ht {
      deny all;
  }

}
```

I get a response (the index.html) I put in `/allsite`s, but using `localhost:8080/site1` or same `site2`, I get a `404 error`. I guess what I am trying to do is use `location ~ /site` as an alias of the root (I tried alias instead of root, but that didn't work).

Am I just fundamentally miss-understanding how location blocks work? or is this a configuration error (In which case any suggestions?).

Comment: You shouldn't be using the `root` directive inside location blocks (see this [link](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#) for details). Also, shouldn't your request be `http://allsites:80/site1`? Your server name is `allsite` so that is what you should be referencing. This server block is listening on 80, do a request using port 8080 won't work.

Comment: I appreciate using `root` in `location` is not best practice, however for this solution it is required (or maybe `alias`). the server can be addressed `localhost:8080/site1`, your method would require a `hosts` entry for `allsites` and this is something the technique I am trying to use avoids, if I did that, I could just setup 2 server references each with a corresponding name in my `hosts` file mapped to localhost.

Comment: PS: `8080` works because I'm running the `nginx` server inside a vm which maps client `80` to host `8080`.

Comment: I see, I didn't know that you did that intentionally. Are you able to access or see PHP files from `http://localhost/allsites`? It might be the case that it's failing at the `fastcgi_pass` for the other sites.

Comment: Yep, I can address any php page in the folder structure (`site1` and `site2` are sub directories of the web root folder (aka `allsites`).